# How can I change the data type in Yii user and rights?

Tags: php, sql, database, yii, yii-extensions

I am a Yiibie , I am using Yii user and rights extension. My problem is I want to change the data type of firstname, lastname from varchar(50) to CHAR(50). Because first name of any user cannot have digits. so How can i do this ?

Comment: Changing a datatype from varchar to char will not prevent digits from being part of the string.  All it will do is to is add trailing spaces.

Comment: Sir then what should I do ?

Comment: I just want to add characters in my firstname and lastname, not a digit.

Comment: By using this extension the tables were auto generated If my recollection is not cheating me. I went to the model to change the datatype just like we do in all other models, but the profile model table coding flew over my head.

Comment: I would suggest stopping digits being used when you are creating and updating the user records. You can use validation rules to stop unwanted characters (or even place limits of the input length) that is independent of the database field length,

Comment: Address the requirement at the point of data entry.  Hint, regular expressions are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegExp in validation rule

In your model

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        .....
        array('firtsname, lastname', 'match' ,
            'pattern'=> '/^[A-Za-z]+$/u',
            'message'=> 'Firtsname and Lastname can contain only [a-zA-Z].'
       ),
        ....
    );
}
```

Comment: Sir take me in your supervision. Awesome it was that simple i did not know that

Comment: Thanks but I'am just a programmers. Just remember that knowledge makes the difference.